# Passing values to Stripe Checkout from shopping cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

My project is a simple e-commerce website that I'm building using React and Stripe for payment handling. I have a checkout page where the products in the shopping cart are stored in the format of an object like so:

```js
cart_items = [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Motherboard 2",
        "price": 100,
        "cat": "Motherboards",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Motherboard 4",
        "price": 100,
        "cat": "Motherboards",
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Motherboard 3",
        "price": 100,
        "cat": "Motherboards",
        "quantity": 1
    }
]
```

On the Stripe docs it uses a form action to send a POST request to the Stripe server to initiate a checkout session so I have this button on my checkout page:

```
<form action="http://localhost:4242/create-checkout-session" method="POST">
<button className='button' type="submit">
    Checkout
</button>
```

and the Stripe server that I have looks like this:

```js
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_51KwxvYGVoSBOtXM2XmVvIJnpCktSICKIYcdWijKEqLtIalOrFyCszRl2iNPLor2fjrOQmuAyTisoVL1v8s8RJvpO00xKsdBlUc');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:4242';

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        line_items: [
            {
                // Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
                price: 'price_1KwyVNGVoSBOtXM2T0zYX0E6',
                quantity: 1,
            },
        ],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: `http://localhost:3000/?success=true`,
        cancel_url: `http://localhost:3000/?canceled=true`,
    });

    res.redirect(303, session.url);
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Running on port 4242'));
```

parameters of `line_items` is what will be displayed in the Stripe checkout page for the user to make payment. Currently it's only a placeholder product but I want to be able to use the values(product name, quantity and price) from my `cart_items` object that is in the checkout page.

Both the React app and the Stripe server are on the same localhost. React is on port 3000 and Stripe server on port 4242.

How can I send these parameters to Stripe? I've looked all over their docs but couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a `<form method="POST">`, you could use it to send the product IDs from your frontend to your backend. Something like this:

Frontend:

```
<form action="http://localhost:4242/create-checkout-session" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="product_ids[]" value="4" />
  <input type="hidden" name="product_ids[]" value="10" />
  <input type="hidden" name="product_ids[]" value="7" />
  <button className='button' type="submit">Checkout</button>
</form>
```

Backend: get the product IDs in the `req.body.product_ids` variable, and find the corresponding price IDs (`pr_xxx`) to send to Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

We actually built shoprocket to do this for you.

Just create/import your products in our dash, connect your stripe account then paste our code snippet into your site and we inject the complete ecommerce experience for you. It takes seconds and the best part is you can connect multiple gateways.

https://shoprocket.io/features/stripe-shopping-cart